# 80s/90's Robot cartoon, one like a Transformer

Tags: story-identification, tv, robots, cartoon

I'm pretty sure the show was out in the 80's or maybe even very early 90's but it could also have been an animated movie (If so would most likely have been a straight to VHS effort)...

Now all I have is a very vague/blurred memory of it so I will try and describe what I recall as best I can:

- I remember there were multiple different coloured robots, one was orange, one was green, pink, blue etc
- Each robot was unique with its own appearance and abilities
- I'm pretty sure one moved around on one wheel while it could shoot out its hands/claws to reach further
- I think one had wheels on the end of its arms which it could fold down and form into a sort of vehicle and go really fast
- I specifically remember a scene where they were trapped in a brown cave looking for a way out but again this is a very old vague memory

I have been searching through the internet with no results at all. It's definitely *not* Transformers, Gobots, Gundam, Mask, Voltron, Mighty Orbots.

Again this could have been a short animated film but I am leaning more towards a series.

UPDATE:

After doing some further research, the character "Grounder" from an old Sonic the Hedgehog series bares a resemblance of what the style of robots looked like but all unique in their own way - Different colours and builds.

Also another show "Super robot monkey team hyperforce go" (SRMTHG) shows the "Monkey/robots" with different accessories for hands - One has drills, another magnets and another has spinning blades... These really triggered the memory for me.

Again the show is a lot older than both of these if my memory serves me correctly.

Comment: Do people drive the robots? How big are they compared to people? Are there people in this show?

Comment: No the robots were their own entities, I am pretty sure there was humans in the show and the robots helped them but again I'm not 100%...
From memory they were of a similar size to a human if there was indeed humans in the show, I don't remember them being the size of transformers for instance...
Thanks!

Comment: Were the humans kids, adolescents, adults? Was it a comedy, goofy and fun, or more serious?

Comment: Again I'm not 100% but if I were to guess I think adolescents/adults...
I think it was more of a fun adventure series but kind of serious, on the same level as Transformers or He-Man or the likes...

Comment: “I'm pretty sure one moved around on one wheel while it could shoot out its hands/claws to reach further...” — that reminded me of [T-Bob from M.A.S.K.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD8EMVurbrM), although I guess you’ve ruled that out.

Comment: I thought T-Bob as well. Guess not.

Comment: Sadly it's definitely not MASK...
Starting to think it could be a figment of my imagination, but its really drilled in from a distant memory...

Comment: I just came across "Grounder" from an old Sonic the Hedgehog series and the design looks identical almost to what I have from memory, but there was more and all had different colours and abilities... Perhaps you could get an idea from looking at a picture of him...

Comment: I've just came across a cartoon network series "super robot monkey team hyperforce go"... there is an image where one of the robots/monkeys has spinning razor blades for hands, one where they have magnets for hands & another has drills for hands & they're all different colours...
Now this is a very similar idea of what I have in my mind but the cartoon was way older and not based on Monkeys or anything?
Perhaps they got some ideas from the show I'm thinking of...

Comment: Anybody else have any ideas?
I am definitely leaning towards a short film now - could even be a holiday special or something along the lines...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the film I was thinking of...

And it turns out it was *[He-Man & She-Ra: a Christmas Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He-Man_%26_She-Ra:_A_Christmas_Special)* from 1985...
As it was a special it was clearly hard to remember...

Anyway the episode had lots of little transformer type characters called "[Manchines](https://he-man.fandom.com/wiki/Manchines)", with each having unique abilities and different colours like I remembered!

[image: Image of the Manchines]

> The Manchines are a race of diminutive humanoids native to Etheria. Their bodies appear to be mostly mechanical, though the name of their species and their tendency to use gendered pronouns when referring to each other imply that they are partially organic. The Manchines live near and are enemies of the Monstroids, who they must fight or avoid to survive.

Thank god I am not crazy and imagined the whole thing! Going to give it a watch shortly for a good kick in the nostalgia's!!!

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a long shot, but any chance you could be thinking of [Robotix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotix)? It was a [movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSlxWE6nMtk) (split up into several episodes) based on a toy line.

Things that fit the description:

- The robots are autonomous; they don't have to be piloted by humans
- The robots all have distinct abilities
- The robots can transform/reconfigure
- One of the robots, [Jerrok](http://robotix-animated.wikia.com/wiki/Jerrok), is basically a torso on a giant wheel who has claws
- Several scenes toward the end of the movie take place in a cave
- There are humans in the show

Things that don't quite fit:

- The robots don't have as varied a color scheme as you remember
- While the robots don't have to have a human pilot, they can and do in some scenes
- The robots are significantly larger than the humans

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with your suggestions but unfortunately it's not the right show...

Guess I may never know - Or there's a good chance it could of been a figment of my imagination haha

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be [Robo Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robo_Force) - the toys where all the robots had suction cups instead of lower bodies. Another wild guess would be [Starriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starriors). The drill on Grounder's face reminds me of a character from each of those series'. Also, neither of them had actual robots but could you be thinking of maybe [Centurions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centurions_(TV_series)#Cast) or [Inhumanoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhumanoids)? The wheels on the arms makes me think of one of Jake Rockwell's suits.

Comment: Ahh really good suggestions - Unfortunately I've already come across all of these and still nothing...
Some do have similarities though... Thanks for your input anyway man!